# Firestore delete ALL fields but ONE

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to delete All fields in a Firestore document apart from ONE field in a SINGLE database write (Without pior reading it)

I know I have a document with some proprieties but I don't know all of them. I want to delete all of these properties except one that I know.

The one that I know is `keep` .

```
            {
                keep: 'keep',
                remove1: 'remove',
                remove2: 'remove',
                remove3: 'remove',
            }
```

The doc after the transaction should be:

```
            {
                keep: 'keep',
            }
```

I could have used `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()` on each of the keys t

Comment: Do you know the value of the `keep` property? Is the `keep` property always the same?

Comment: No, I don't know. It is not always the same. We just leave it as it is

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name and the value of the field you want to keep, you can just overwrite the document with an object that only contains the property you know:

```
const keepValue = ...;
db.collection('mycollection').doc('mydoc').
set(
  { keep: keepValue }
);
```

Since we use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) method without the merge option, all the fields in the document will be overwritten with the object passed to the `set()` method.

---

If you don't know the value (or the name) of the field you want to keep, you will need to read the document, in order to find this value or name.

Comment: But where do you get the keepValue ?

Comment: You need to read it before. So the answer to "Is it possible ... without prior reading it" is no.